# How to add more fields to blog posts in meezanine CMS?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am developing an cms website by using Mezzanine CMS. I want to add the field as author name and image in blog post. can anyone help me how can i  add custom fields in mezzanine's inbuilt blog application

Comment: The [Mezzanine documentation](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#creating-custom-content-types) describes how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to achieve this, 
1. Inject extra fields 
2. Extend the blog post model of mezzanine for more details on extending blog model visit https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mezzanine-users/UWLhcBb_fLs